# Program in C to find user defined average with for loop

Tags: c

The average call is not outputting the right average. Any way someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{

    int num=0;
    int counter=0;
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    float avg=0;

    printf("Numver of values to be entered: \n");
    scanf("%d", &counter);

    for (num=1;num<=counter;num++)
    {
        printf("Please enter value %d :",num);
        scanf("%d",&i);
        sum +=i;
    }
    avg=sum/num;//This portion isnt working and I cant figure out why
    printf("The average is : %f\n",avg);
}
```

Output I'm getting.

/workspace $ gcc -o AvgFor AvgFor.c

/workspace $ ./AvgFor

Numver of values to be entered: 
2
Please enter value 1 :10
Please enter value 2 :10
The average is : 6.000000

What I'm expecting is 10 + 10 = 20. Then 20/2=10

Comment: How about some sample input and output?

Comment: Please show an example of input, expected and actual output.

Comment: What is "user defined average"? Either it is an average or not.

Comment: don't you want to do `sum/counter` since `num` will have incremented past `counter` during the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate `sum/num`, both arguments are of type `int` so integer division is performed, which means any fractional portion is truncated.  This happens *before* the result is assigned to `avg`.

You need to cast at least one argument to `float` to perform floating point division:

```
avg = (float)sum/num;
```

Answer (score 1):

sum and num are both integers so will provide an integer answer, even though you are assigning it to a float afterwards.

Change sum to a float or double and it allow decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

`sum/num` is an integer division.  Use the type of the destination.  I prefer to avoid casts as they can truncate information unexpectedly as code is updated.

```
avg = sum;
avg /= num;

// alternative
avg = 1.0*sum/num;
```

Little reason to use `float` here for the quotient, recommend `double`.

```
// float avg=0;
double avg=0;
```

Off by 1, use `counter`. [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121630/program-in-c-to-find-user-defined-average-with-for-loop#comment93137950_53121630)

```
avg = sum;
avg /=counter;
```

Iteration to `<` is more idiomatic in C than `<=`. Either way works here given the above division is done right.

```
// for (num=1;num<=counter;num++)
for (num=0; num<counter; num++)
  printf("Please enter value %d :",num+1);
```

Comment: This doesnt fix the problem of it not averaging right. Also, if I make the changes in the for loop, the statement Please enter value: reads as 0, 1, 2 and so forth. People don't talk like that.

Comment: @HenryGibbs This answer does not suggest "Please enter value 0", it suggests "Please enter value 1".  Perhaps with the `num=0; num<counter; num++`, the common C idiom, you did not notice `... value %d :",num+1);`?

Comment: @HenryGibbs This answer does fix a problem in how the original code calculated average. What does your code, after the loop, look like?  What values  were entered, seen and expected?

Comment: Output I'm getting.

/workspace $ gcc -o AvgFor AvgFor.c

/workspace $ ./AvgFor

Numver of values to be entered: 2 Please enter value 1 :10 Please enter value 2 :10 The average is : 6.000000

What I'm expecting is 10 + 10 = 20. Then 20/2=10

Comment: @HenryGibbs  6 would follow with your original code.`avg = sum;
avg /= counter;` results in 10.